# MySQL - Update Columns in Two Tables After Comparing Tables

Tags: mysql

I am by no means a MySQL expert. That said, I've encountered a problem with cross table matching and data updates. Trust me I did search for quite awhile before posting, but every solution I found mentioned joining the tables and my queries kept freezing when I tried.

The below query selects all the data I want to manipulate:

```
SELECT t1.1, t2.1, t1.2, t2.2, t1.3, t2.3, t1.4, t2.4
FROM t1, t2
WHERE 
t1.1='1111111' &&
t1.1 = t2.1 &&
t1.2 = t2.2 &&
t1.3 = t2.3 &&
t1.4 = t2.4 &&
;
```

This appears to work fine and shows me what I want to see. However, next I want to update an additional column from t1 and a column from t2 based on the results found above and that's where I'm stuck.

Can I morph this into some sort of update query which uses a similar WHERE section, but can also update a column from both t1 and t2 (additional column, say t1.5 and t2.5)?

*Note, these tables do not have all identical columns, but all the above in WHERE overlap*

Comment: The `JOIN` version is the only way I know of. Maybe you just need to narrow things down more so there's less work for MySQL to do?

Comment: Posted my fixes/updates below. Ended up being a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all the things I had tried probably would have worked fine. However, the database/tables I was working with had never been indexed. My queries appeared to hang, but in reality probably were just taking ages to finish.

Secondly, some of the values in one table were set as varchar instead of int. Until we fixed this, even indexing couldn't help these comparisons.

I was able to get this working using the following query after the updates above, now in a fraction of a second:

```
UPDATE t1, t2
SET t1.5="x", t2.5="x"
FROM t1, t2
WHERE 
t1.1='1111111' &&
t1.1 = t2.1 &&
t1.2 = t2.2 &&
t1.3 = t2.3 &&
t1.4 = t2.4 &&
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
UPDATE t1
SET ...
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT a.id
  FROM t1 a, t2 b
  WHERE
    a.1 = '1111111' AND
    a.1 = b.1 AND
    a.2 = b.2 AND
    a.3 = b.3 AND
    a.4 = b.4 AND
)
```

The UPDATE query will be nice and clean with a subquery that's big and JOINy.

I've no idea how your `SET` part would look, so I don't know if this'll work.